# what is the difference between kind of/to , nice of/to?

Tags: meaning, difference

1. It was kind of him to let me stay in his house.

It was nice of him to let me stay in his house.

2. She is always very nice to me. She is friendly.

She is always kind to me. She is friendly.

Comment: _Nice_ is an all-purpose word indicating approval, that can be used in all sorts of contexts but doesn't show much imagination (a nice day, a nice meal, a nice person etc. etc.).

Comment: As a child I was told never to use _nice_ except in the meaning of exact, probably for the reasons @KateBunting outlines.